# parcolumns and qtree

Tags: columns, linguistics, qtree, parcolumns

I need to create two columns with different widths. I am trying to use the `parcolumns` package, but I can't make it work properly. Here is the code and the result:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{parcolumns, linguex, qtree, lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}[colwidths={1=0.6\linewidth}]{2}

\colchunk[1]{%
\lipsum[1]}

\colchunk[2]{%
\ex. {\small {\scshape \Tree [.{...} [.XP [.\framebox{Spec} ] [. [.X ] [.{...} \phantom{...} \qroof{ZP}.YP ]]]]}} \label{CP} \vspace{.5cm}

}
\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I checked the `parcolumn` documentation, but I don't seem to find any mention as to how to fix this problem. Any solution/alternative?

Comment: What exactly is the problem, the vertical alignment of the example/tree or the big gap in the first column or both?  The tree makes it worse, but part of the problem seems to be with `linguex`

Comment: And that seems to be a problem with any list (`enumerate` will show the same problem.)

Comment: Related: [Different column widths using multicol](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/89721)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @AlanMunn, but that solution doesn't seem to work too: is there any way to decide where to break the column?